# Call private method from public method?

Tags: javascript

I´ve defined a class like this:

```
function Class1(){
    this.Func1 = function(){
       /* Methods and vars */
    };

    function Func2(){
       /* Methods and vars */
    };

};
```

I want to find out a way to call the public method (or get the value of a public variable) from the private one (Func2()). Any sugestions?

Pd: Sorry if the terminology I used is strongly oriented to objects, because I am a C++ programer, and I'm kinda newby in javascript programming.

Comment: `Func2` is actually the "private method" here, and `Func1` "public".

Comment: Sorry, I was so fast at wirting the question

Comment: You should write 'this.Func1 = new function()' instead of 'this.Func1() = new function()'

Comment: A little nitpicking here: you should write most functions and methods with camelCase (first letter lowercase) Write your constructor-functions with CamelCase (first letter uppercase). Source: http://javascript.crockford.com/code.html

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From `Func1`, you can call `Func2` directly:

```
this.Func1 = function() {
  Func2();
};
```

However, you cannot do the same to call `Func1` from `Func2` because `Func2` will (probably) have a different scope and different definition of `this` when it is called; `this.Func1` will be undefined. As alx suggested below, you can save the scope using another variable that will retain its value when used from the inside function. You can also save a reference to `Func1` in local scope as follows:

```
var Func1 = this.Func1 = function() {
  // fun stuff
};

function Func2() {
  Func1();
}
```

This works because it does not rely on the changing reference `this`.

Comment: This will only work if `Func2` is called with `.apply(this)` or `.call(this)`.

Comment: Not *only*, but that is one way. It depends on how Func2 is called and since the OP hasn't provided any way of calling it (nor has the accepted answer) then we don't know how to call *Func1* from it.

Comment: Ben - that answer is insufficient. How *Func2* calls *Func1* is dependent on how *Func2* was called. You don't show that, nor does the OP so you have no idea what `this` inside *Func2* will reference.

Comment: Sorry, that was me not thinking. Just rewrote my answer.

Answer (score 7):

use closure:

```
function Class1(){
        this.Func1 = function(){
           /* Methods and vars */
        };

        var me = this;

        function Func2(){
           me.Func1();
        };

    };
```

Answer (score -1):

being declared in the same scope, the public method is aware of the private one, thus you can just simply call it :

```
function Object1(){
    this.publicMethod = function(){         
        alert("I'm a public method ;)");
    };
    var that = this;
    function privateMethod(){
        return that.publicMethod.apply(that,arguments);
    };
};
```

Comment: The value of `this' in "privateMethod" is unknown since you haven't shown how to call it.