# How to access private method from another private method in Javascript

Tags: javascript, oop, private

I was wondering if it was possible to call a private method from another private method on Javascript. I have some code like the following:

```
function Balloon() {
function density( altitude, gas ) {
  /* KG/CU M */

  var gas = { 
   /* GAS DEFINATIONS - wolframalpha.com */
   "hydrogen" : .00100794,
   "helium"   : .004002602,
   "nitrogen" : .0140067,
   "methane"  : .0160425,
   "ammonia"  : .0170305,
   "neon"     : .0201791,
   "dry air"  : .0289644 
  }

  var alt = {
   /* CONSTANTS - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Density_of_air#Altitude */
   "p0" : 101325,   // Sea level standard atmospheric pressure (Pa)
   "T0" : 288.15,   // Sea level standard temperature (K) 
   "g"  : 9.80665,  // Earth-surface gravitational acceleration (m/s^2)
   "L"  : 0.0065,   // Temperature lapse rate (K/m)
   "R"  : 8.31447   // Universal gas constant (mol * K)
  }

  var temperature = alt["T0"] - alt["L"] * altitude;
  var pressure    = alt["p0"] * (1 - (( alt["L"] * altitude ) / alt["T0"] )) ^ (( alt["g"] * gas[gas] ) / ( alt["R"] * alt["L"] ));
  var density     = ( pressure * gas[gas] ) / ( alt["R"] * temperature );

  return density;
 }

 function lift( altitude, gas ) {
  /* KG/CU M */

  return density( altitude, "dry air" ) - density( altitude, gas ); 
 }

 this.requiredGas = function( altitude, gas, ratio, weight ) {
  return (( weight / 1000 ) * ratio ) / lift( altitude, gas );
 }
}
```

and am trying to access it like:

```
balloon = new Balloon();
var required = balloon.requiredGas(10, "helium", 1.5, 4530);
```

I have seen people declare `this` from outside the private functions [like so](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6420825/call-private-method-from-public-method), but don't know if that's how to approach this one.

Comment: Your code looks fine. What's not working about it?

Comment: I call balloon.requiredGas and get a NaN. lift() is not calling density().

Comment: @KyleHotchkiss: Are you sure it isn't? `density` is in the same scope as `lift` so that is no problem. It sounds more like you are not passing valid numbers to the function.

Comment: `lift` is calling `density`; if you put an `alert` or `console.log` at the top of `density` you will see this to be true. The problem is likely that you are dividing by zero, i.e. that `lift` returns `0`.

Comment: @Domenic: `"dry air"` is not a valid number, that's why it returns `NaN` (n your case). Devision by `0` returns `Infinity`.

Comment: @Kyle: What is the implementation of `density`?

Comment: @Flex Kling: haha yes, that's true. Let's try http://jsfiddle.net/SLQTd/1 instead.

Comment: Code runs, http://jsbin.com/amawun/2/ what does `function density` look like?

Comment: I've put the code above.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are overriding the argument you pass into your `density` function with the `gas` array.

See, it works fine once I rename it!

http://jsfiddle.net/pEcMJ/

Comment: Whoa. I didn't even think it was that. Thanks for pointing out my issue man!

Comment: @josh No, you're just *fast*. :-)

Answer (score 2):

You are redefining your method parameter `function density( altitude, gas )` with an object `var gas ={}`

Answer (score 1):

This line produces the NAN

```
var pressure    = alt["p0"] * (1 - (( alt["L"] * altitude ) / alt["T0"] )) ^ (( alt["g"] * gas[gas] ) / ( alt["R"] * alt["L"] ));
```

It is `gas[gas]` :)